# Creating a progress bar for BASH script exporting system log files

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

Essentially for a set number of systems logs pulled and exported I need to indicate the scripts progress by printing a character "#". This should eventually create a progress bar with a width of 60. Something like what's presented below: `#############################################` ,additionally I need the characters to build from left to right indicating the progression of the script.

The Question/Problem that this code was based off of goes as follows: "Use a separate invocation of `wevtutil el` to get the count of the number of logs and scale this to,say, a width of 60."

```
SYSNAM=$(hostname)
LOGDIR=${1:-/tmp/${SYSNAM}_logs}

i=0
LOGCOUNT=$( wevtutil el | wc -l )
x=$(( LOGCOUNT/60 ))

wevtutil el | while read ALOG
do
        ALOG="${ALOG%$'\r'}"
        printf "${ALOG}:\r"
        SAFNAM="${ALOG// /_}"
        SAFNAM="${SAFNAM//\//-}"
        wevtutil epl "$ALOG" "${SYSNAM}_${SAFNAM}.evtx"


done
```

I've attempted methods such as using `echo -ne "#"`, and `printf "#%0.s"` however the issue that I encounter is that the "#" characters gets printed with each instance of the name of the log file being retrieved; also the pattern is printed vertically rather than horizontally.

```
LOGCOUNT=$( wevtutil el | wc -l )
x=$(( LOGCOUNT/60 ))

echo  -ne "["
for i in {1..60}
do
        if [[ $(( x*i )) != $LOGCOUNT ]]
        then
                echo -ne "#"
                #printf '#%0.s'
        fi

done
echo "]"
printf "\n"
echo "Transfer Complete."
echo "Total Log Files Transferred: $LOGCOUNT"
```

I tried previously integrating this code into the first block but no luck. But something tells me that I don't need to establish a whole new loop, I keep thinking that the first block of code only needs a few lines of modification. Anyhow sorry for the lengthy explanation, please let me know if anything additional is needed for assistance--Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to make the display look like? Are you trying to put the current filename and `#######` bar on different lines? If so, you need some way to bounce back & forth to update both; if not, you need to figure out how to fit both on a single line.

Comment: Yes that is correct, if possible I would like to display both the current file being fetched/exported and the progress bar "###..." on different lines. Sorry if my question was incorrectly formatted or poorly, worded this is the first time asking for help via the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of this answer I'm going to assume the desired output is a 2-liner that looks something like:

```
$ statbar
file: /bin/cygdbusmenu-qt5-2.dll
[########                            ]
```

The following may not work for everyone as it comes down to individual terminal attributes and how they can(not) be manipulated by `tput` (ie, ymmv) ...

For my sample script I'm going to loop through the contents of `/bin`, printing the name of each file as I process it, while updating the status bar with a new '#' after each 20 files:

- there are 719 files under my `/bin` so there should be 35 `#'s` in my status bar (I add an extra `#` at the end once processing has completed)
- we'll use a few `tput` commands to handle cursor/line movement, plus erasing previous output from a line
- for printing the status bar I've pre-calculated the number of `#'s` and then use 2 variables ... `$barspace` for spaces, `$barhash` for `#'s`; for each 20 files I strip a space off `$barspace` and add a single `#` to `$barhash`; by (re)printing these 2x variables every 20x files I get the appearance of a moving status bar

Putting this all together:

```
$ cat statbar
clear              # make sure we have plenty of room to display our status bar;
                   # if we're at the bottom of the console/window and we cause the
                   # windows to 'scroll up' then 'tput sc/rc' will not work

tput sc            # save pointer/reference to current terminal line
erase=$(tput el)   # save control code for 'erase (rest of) line'

# init some variables; get a count of the number of files so we can pre-calculate the total length of our status bar

modcount=20
filecount=$(find /bin -type f | wc -l)

# generate a string of filecount/20+1 spaces (35+1 for my particular /bin)

barspace=

for ((i=1; i<=(filecount/modcount+1); i++))
do
        barspace="${barspace} "
done

barhash=           # start with no #'s for this variable

filecount=0        # we'll re-use this variable to keep track of # of files processed so need to reset

while read -r filename
do
        filecount=$((filecount+1))

        tput rc    # return cursor to previously saved terminal line (tput sc)

        # print filename (1st line of output); if shorter than previous filename we need to erase rest of line

        printf "file: ${filename}${erase}\n"

        # print our status bar (2nd line of output) on the first and every ${modcount} pass through loop; 

        if   [ ${filecount} -eq 1 ]
        then
                printf "[${barhash}${barspace}]\n"

        elif [[ $((filecount % ${modcount} )) -eq 0 ]]
        then
                # for every ${modcount}th file we ...

                barspace=${barspace:1:100000}         # strip a space from barspace
                barhash="${barhash}#"                 # add a '#' to barhash
                printf "[${barhash}${barspace}]\n"    # print our new status bar
        fi

done < <(find /bin -type f | sort -V)

# finish up the status bar (should only be 1 space left to 'convert' to a '#')

tput rc

printf "file: -- DONE --\n"

if [ ${#barspace} -gt 0 ]
then
        barspace=${barspace:1:100000}
        barhash="${barhash}#"
fi

printf "[${barhash}${barspace}]\n"
```

NOTE: While testing I had to periodically reset my terminal in order for the `tput` commands to function properly, eg:

```
$ reset
$ statbar
```

I couldn't get the above to work on any of the (internet) fiddle sites (basically having problems getting `tput` to work with the web-based 'terminals').

Here's a gif displaying the behavior ...

[image]

NOTES:

- the script **does** print every filename to stdout but since this script isn't actually doing anything with the files in question a) the `printfs` occur quite rapidly and b) the video/gif only captures a (relatively) few fleeting images ("Duh, Mark!" ?)
- the last `printf "file: -- DONE --\n"` was added after I created the gif, and I'm being lazy by not generating and uploading a new gif

Comment: I tried modifying your code a bit according to what I need the progress bar to be monitoring. For the most part it works EXCEPT towards the end of the script when one last "#" is needed to complete the progress bar, I get the output ```[#                                           ]``` followed by a complete a 90% complete status bar ```[################## ]```. That aside I appreciate the assistance provided thus far I'm just trying  to figure out why this keeps occurring.

Comment: hard to say what the issue might be without seeing the actual code; the single `#` output sounds like there may be a typo in the `${barhash}` reference, eg, `${barash}#` (missing the first 'h') will result in a single `#`

Comment: Sorry kinda new to Stack and having issues with the code block syntax i'm still digging on how to get it working but the issues seems to be occurring from ``` tput rc ``` to ```printf "[${barhash}${barspace}]\n" ``` , right after the while loop. Also I noticed that ```printf "file: -- DONE --\n"```, is outputting as ```file: -- DONE --code``` --PS Double checked the syntax and variables everything seems to be legit (i.e. no spelling errors)

Comment: I've cut-n-pasted directly from my answer into my bash/cmd window, run the script, and it works as expected, so it's hard to ascertain what the issue is (eg, a typo in the code changes, something different with your version of bash, etc) without seeing all of your modified code

Comment: Alright let me see if there is a way that I can post a descent chunk of code here, although it seems I am limited by the amount of characters I can use. Do you think it could be because I'm using "Git Bash"?

Comment: don't cut-n-paste into this comment window; either add a section on the end of your question (above), or open/create a new question

Comment: Here are two lines that I added to the while loop that could be affecting things. 1.) ```filename="${filename%$'\r'}"``` 
  2.) ```printf "log files: ${filename}${erase}\r\n"```, in this order directly after the ```tput rc``` within the while loop. I think this could be the source of the problem

Comment: if you added a line to the output (ie, total of 3 lines of output constantly being overwritten), then you likely need to take into consideration that 3rd line when printing the last couple lines of output (after the `while` loop); whether you print that 3rd line again, skip past with a blank line (and no `erase`), or print something new to the 3rd line ... depends on what you expect to see in the **final** 3 lines of ourput ...

Comment: I will keep tweaking the code I think I may have found the source the error but will post a new question if the issue continues to persist.